# Python Maya reference

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to create a script to reference different light rigs and clean them in the same window. Since I have more than one I would like to switch between them and that is the part where the script breaks.

Here is what I tried:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class ReferenceUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window_name = "template"
        self.file_paths = ["D:\\Estudos\\Cenas\\fred\\fred.0001.mb", "D:\\Estudos\\Cenas\\fred\\fred.0002.mb", "D:\\Estudos\\Cenas\\fred\\fred.0003.mb"]
        self.ref_name = "template"
        self.current_file = self.file_paths[0]

    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window_name, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window_name)

        self.window = cmds.window(self.window_name, title=self.window_name)

        self.main_layout = cmds.columnLayout()
        self.file_path_selector = cmds.optionMenuGrp(label="File Path")
        for file_path in self.file_paths:
            cmds.menuItem(label=file_path)

        self.reference_button = cmds.button(label="Add Reference", 
                            command=lambda x: self.add_reference())

        self.switch_button = cmds.button(label="Switch Reference",
                            command=lambda x: self.switch_reference())

        self.clean_button = cmds.button(label="Clean All References",
                            command=lambda x: self.clean_references())

        cmds.showWindow(self.window)

    def add_reference(self):
        file_path = cmds.optionMenuGrp(self.file_path_selector, query=True, value=True)
        cmds.file(file_path, reference=True, namespace=self.ref_name)
        self.current_file = file_path

    def switch_reference(self):
        file_path = cmds.optionMenuGrp(self.file_path_selector, query=True, value=True)
        if file_path != self.current_file:
            cmds.file(file_path, edit=True, force=True, options="v=0;", loadReferenceDepth="all", namespace=self.ref_name)
            self.current_file = file_path
        else:
            cmds.warning("The selected file is already loaded")

    def clean_references(self):
        references = cmds.ls(references=True)
        for ref in references:
            cmds.file(removeReference=True, referenceNode=ref, type='mayaAscii')

reference_manager = ReferenceUI()
reference_manager.create()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the script breaks"?

Comment: It doesn't switch the file and sometimes crashes Maya

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your script and there are two issues I found

- when you remove reference you have a type mayaAscii, while I see that your references files have extension .mb, so I assume they are binary. I've tried with ascii reference files for the test
- for swapping references there is a trick to use file cmd with arguments of loading your reference from namespace (where name should have RN postfix) and specify a new reference file path

here is an updated script

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class ReferenceUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window_name = "template"
        self.file_paths = ["C:\\work\\box01.ma", "C:\\work\\cone01.ma"]
        self.ref_name = "template"
        self.current_file = self.file_paths[0]

    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window_name, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window_name)

        self.window = cmds.window(self.window_name, title=self.window_name)

        self.main_layout = cmds.columnLayout()
        self.file_path_selector = cmds.optionMenuGrp(label="File Path")
        for file_path in self.file_paths:
            cmds.menuItem(label=file_path)

        self.reference_button = cmds.button(label="Add Reference", 
                            command=lambda x: self.add_reference())

        self.switch_button = cmds.button(label="Switch Reference",
                            command=lambda x: self.switch_reference())

        self.clean_button = cmds.button(label="Clean All References",
                            command=lambda x: self.clean_references())

        cmds.showWindow(self.window)

    def add_reference(self):
        file_path = cmds.optionMenuGrp(self.file_path_selector, query=True, value=True)
        cmds.file(file_path, reference=True, namespace=self.ref_name)
        self.current_file = file_path

    def switch_reference(self):
        file_path = cmds.optionMenuGrp(self.file_path_selector, query=True, value=True)
        if file_path != self.current_file:
            cmds.file(file_path, options="v=0;", type="mayaAscii", loadReference="templateRN")
            self.current_file = file_path
        else:
            cmds.warning("The selected file is already loaded")

    def clean_references(self):
        references = cmds.ls(references=True)
        for ref in references:
            cmds.file(removeReference=True, referenceNode=ref, type='mayaAscii')

reference_manager = ReferenceUI()
reference_manager.create()
```